# existe alguma forma de fazer várias consultas mysql e se alguma falhar desfazer todas?

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se o mysql possui algum recurso semelhante. Preciso criar uma aplicação e é necessário garantir que todos as sub consultas retornem sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe, para isso você utiliza a [Transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), nele você todas as queries que forem executadas dentro da transação podem ser desfeitas (`rollback`) ou salvas (`commit`).

O MySQLi já possui suporte, basta utilizar:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($link);
```

Assim como desligar o "auto-commit", utilizando:

```
mysqli_autocommit($link, false);
```

Dessa forma todas as queries executadas a partir do $link serão parte da Transaction, até que um `commit` ou `rollback` seja feito.

Para salvar as informações da transação utilize:

```
mysqli_commit($link);
```

Para descartar as alterações, utilize:

```
mysqli_rollback($link);
```

---

Um exemplo simples:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($con);
mysqli_autocommit($con, false);

$logModificacao = mysqli_query($con, '
   INSERT INTO `log_alteracao_conta`(`idUsuario`, `Quando`, `QualMudanca`) 
     VALUES ("1","2017-04-26 20:03:00", "1")
');
$logModificacao = mysqli_affected_rows($con) === 1;

$alteraConta = mysqli_query($con, '
   UPDATE usuario 
    SET nome = "zileknI"
     WHERE id = "1" AND nome = "Inkeliz"
');
$alteraConta = mysqli_affected_rows($con) === 1;

if($alteraNome && $logModificacao){
    mysqli_commit($con);
}else{
    mysqli_rollback($con);
}
```

Neste caso uma tabela salva as datas que todas as alterações na conta foram feitas e o que foi modificado e a segunda query irá de fato alterar o nome do usuário. Se uma delas não for feita irá cair no `rollback`.

Também é possível utilizar sem o `mysqli_affected_rows`, porém em alguns casos bem obscuros pode não ser apontado problema pelo MySQL e não ser inserido dados.